# how to get rid of ReferenceError: window is not defined in Java Script,and what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have just started learning JavaScript and i am using Atom text editor, and installed NodeJS v14.7.0 version.
I have written only one line of code which is:--

```
window.alert("Hello MySelf");
```

when i run the program using *ctrl+shift+B* i encountered with an error which does't look like any syntax error.

**Below i am posting the error..**

```
window.alert('Hello World');
^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at [stdin]:58:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:132:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:315:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:98:25)
    at internal/main/eval_stdin.js:29:5
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/process/execution.js:211:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1244:12)
[Finished in 8.238s]
```

I run it with Webstorm also but unfortunately it not helped.
I searched it on google but unable to understand what the problem is.
Please help me to get out of this rid.
Thanks in advance..
Your words are value for me..

Comment: `window` is a global variable in web browsers. There is a global variable named `global` in Node.js, but it doesn't have `alert` method.

Comment: So what i have to do please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Make an HTML file which runs a script:

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```js
window.alert("Hello MySelf");
```

There would be way to launch a browser with using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> but for now, open `test.html` file with a web browser like Chrome instead.

Comment: Okh i understand but i am learning from an video lecture and for him without using html file he is able to run this program.By the way Thanks..I appreciate your help.

Comment: Then that lecture might instruct how the project should be set. You may missed it.